# How do you save the images that are embedded in the placeholders of a pptx file using python?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I can extract all the images from the shapes of a slide, as shown in the code below. The problem comes when an image is embedded in a placeholder. I have no idea how to get the images from those placeholders, and the documentation to me isn't clear.

Note also that I have a minimum width limit for the kind of images I want, hence I have "shape.width > 250000" in the code

```
import os
import pptx
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE_TYPE

ppFileName = "Test.pptx"

directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
imageDirectory = directory + "\\Images " + ppFileName.replace(".pptx","")
if not os.path.exists(imageDirectory):
    os.makedirs(imageDirectory)

def saveImage(shape,slideNumber,imageNumber):
    image = shape.image
    imageBytes = image.blob
    imageFileName = f"Slide {slideNumber} Image {imageNumber}.{image.ext}"
    imagePath = imageDirectory + "\\" + imageFileName
    with open(imagePath, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(imageBytes)
    imageNumber += 1

prs = pptx.Presentation(directory + "\\" + ppFileName)
slides = prs.slides
slideNumber = 0
for slide in slides:
    imageNumber = 0
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.PICTURE and shape.width > 250000:
            saveImage(shape,slideNumber,imageNumber)
        elif shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.GROUP and shape.width > 250000:
            for s in shape.shapes:
                saveImage(s,slideNumber,imageNumber)
    slideNumber += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured it out.

Just added these three lines of code:

```
for shape in slide.placeholders:
        if hasattr(shape, "image") and shape.width > 250000:
            saveImage(shape,slideNumber,imageNumber)
```